# clean way to append a short integer to a CodedOutputStream

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using google protocol buffers, I need to prefix my message with the size as a 16 bit int.
I did not find protocol buffer method to write 16 bit int

I am a c++ guy, with little knowledge of java.

so far I am doing so using:

```
            // protomessage is a protocol buffer message
            // assuming protomessage.toByteArray().length < short.MAX_value
            ByteArrayOutputStream rawOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CodedOutputStream output = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(rawOutput);

            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
            b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            b.putShort((short) (protomessage.toByteArray().length));
            output.writeRawBytes(b.array())
```

Is that the correct way ? (honestly it doesnt feel right)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it directly given you know exactly two bytes are needed:

```
int len = protomessage.toByteArray().length;
output.writeRawBytes(new Byte[]{
        (byte) ((len >>> 8) & 0xff), 
        (byte) (len & 0xff)
     });
```

Though this doesn't check for overflows.

Comment: I ll accept this answer, would you recommend your solution over mine ? or both are fine ?

Comment: Mine is probably quicker but yours is somewhat more readable, IMHO. Also I haven't debugged mine :-)